# Finding #Groupoid like subsets

Tags: group-theory

Given $S=\{x \in \mathbb{R}: 1 \leq |x| \leq 100\}$, find all subsets $M$ of $S$ such that for all $x$, $y$ in $M$, their product $xy$ is also in $M$.

My attempt:

If any number with magnitude greater than $1$ is present, then it cannot be part of such a subset, since repeated operations with itself will result in a very large element. So my guess is $M = \{1\}, \{-1,1\}$, hence only two possibilities. Am I missing anything? Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Your argument is spot on.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks for your clarification.